# Error de envío de un array al controlador con AJAX - MVC - C#

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc

Tengo problemas con el pasaje de un array al controlador via Ajax, ya busque por todos lados y probe mil cosa. La cuestión es que al disparar la funcion desde el navegador, el controlador me retorna la vista pero sin el array que le había pasado. Es más en la url del navegador no se concatena ningún parametro, soló, el controlador y la Acción. Lo llamativo es que en la consola de depuración del VS figura el GET con la url completa de parametros (o sea todo el array), doy click en ese vinculo y en la ventana de exploración interna de VS veo todo el array, inclusive si coloca esa url en navegador tambien, veo todo el array devuelto por el controlador. Si alguien me pudiera decir que es, paso el código, pd datos simples tampoco pasan. Gracias. 
Este es el Controlador

```
public ActionResult Pruebas(string value)
    {
        ViewBag.contenido = value;

        // return Json("output", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return View();
    }
}   


function pasar() {


    var valueArray = [];

    valueArray.push("val1");
    valueArray.push("val2");
    valueArray.push("val3");
    valueArray.push("val4");
    valueArray.push("val5");


        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Pruebas',
            type: "GET",
            data: { value: valueArray.toString()}, 
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,

            success: function (data) {

            }

    });

}
```

Comment: Podrias poner como recibes el arreglo en tu método ??

Comment: también proble recibiendo con (string [] value)  y nada..Aunque también funciona, mostrando todo el array  mediante la url mostrada en la consola  del VS. Agregue el controlador ahi en el código. El string llega null siempre

Comment: probé tu código y funciona bien

Comment: gracias Xique. ahora logre que llegue el array pero no redireciona mostrando la vista. Lo que yo quiero es que luego de pasar el array, obtener la vista con el ViewBag mostrando el array. Ademas de mandar el array debo obtener la vista. En el debug se observa que hay retorno de la vista, que el VBag se setea y todo los demas pero no redireciona. Habras que hacer algun redirect o algo en el escript. Y como seria?

Comment: no redireciono ya fue.. pero funciona, el array pasa y puedo operar

Comment: y como regresas a la vista ?  o que retornas ?

Comment: el return view lo hace el controlador, pero en el navegador no se muestra(no hay un redirección con la url del GET). Con el array pasado opero en una bd , eso funciona bien y luego en el succes del script tiro un alert donde dice que esta todo bien y listo.  Por ahora eso me sirve.